# Is it possible to declare a constrained data type using record syntax?

Tags: haskell, syntax, gadt

Is it possible to declare a [constrained data type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Data_declaration_with_constraint) using [record syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes#Named_Fields_.28Record_Syntax.29)? My attempt

```
data ConstrainedRecord a where
  ConstrainedRecord :: Num a => { first :: a, second :: a }
```

causes GHC to complain "Record syntax is illegal here".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but in [GADT syntax](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-algebraic-data-types-gadts) you always have to explicitly specify the return type of the constructor:

```
data ConstrainedRecord a where
  ConstrainedRecord :: Num a => { first :: a, second :: a } -> ConstrainedRecord a
```

(Also, this may come handy:

```
deriving instance (Show a) => Show (ConstrainedRecord a)
```

using `StandaloneDeriving`, since a normal `deriving` does not work.)